Moving intersecting point at specific distance along line in QGIS
I am sure there is an easy way to do this but I can't think of anything, as I need to do several watercourses, otherwise I would just manually figure it out.
I have created a point file where two crosses intersect a polygon - one upstream and one downstream with specific distances that I need upstream and downstream.
Is there any tool I can use to create a point along the line offset by a specified distance (see the black crosses in the image below)? For this instance a cross 100m up along the long and 500m down the line (I can't just use buffers because the line curves).


You can use QGIS expressions with Geometry by expression (see also here) and the function line_locate_point() to get the distance of the current point along the line and then create a new point with the same distance along the ling, +/- a fixed value, using line_interpolate_point().
This is the expression to move the points for 100 meters along the line; change length and add a - (minus) to the value to create the points in the other direction (upstream/downstream):
with_variable(
    'nearest_line',
    overlay_nearest ('line_layer_name',@geometry)[0],
line_interpolate_point(
    @nearest_line,
    line_locate_point (@nearest_line, @geometry) - 100 -- change distance here
)
)

Alternatively, you could use Interpolate point on line.
Red. Initial points, yellow: points moved 100 m along the line. Straight line measurement tool shows the point is indeed 100 m away along the line, not in beeline direction:


Worked like a charm! I had the distance as an attribute so I just replaced -100 with that field
